# How can I export the privileges from MySQL and then import to a new server?

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, database-administration, mysql-replication

I know how to export/import the databases using mysqldump & that's fine but how do I get the privileges into the new server.

For extra points, there are a couple of existing databases on the new one already, how do I import the old servers privileges without nuking the couple existing of ones.

Old server: 5.0.67-community

New server: 5.0.51a-24+lenny1

EDIT: I've got a dump of the db 'mysql' from the Old Server & now want to know the proper way to merge with the 'mysql' db on the New Server.

I tried a straight 'Import' using phpMyAdmin and ended up with an error regarding a duplicate (one that I've already migrated manually).

Anyone got an elegant way of merging the two 'mysql' databases?

Comment: 1. Is it a requirement for you to use PHPMyAdmin?  
If it is I will write some PHPMyAdmin specific instructions for you.  
 2. From PHPMyAdmin if you try to "select * from mysql.user limit 1;" do you get results or an error.

Comment: As I mentioned below, I think Richard's mygrants script is a good way to get grant info. However, you can also try editing the dump file to comment out INSERTs to the user table for users who already exist. Privileges for the dbs restored from the old server will then be copied. If you've already assigned privileges manually for some of the dbs you restored to the new box, look for these table names in the privilege files and comment these out, too. Don't forget a flush_privileges afterwards. Good description of the mysql db at: http://www.grahamwideman.com/gw/tech/mysql/perms/index.htm

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Do not mess with the mysql db. There is a lot more going on there than just the users table. Your best bet is the "[SHOW GRANTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-grants.html) FOR" command. I have a lot of CLI maintenance aliases and functions in my .bashrc (actually my .bash_aliases that I source in my .bashrc). This function:

```
mygrants()
{
  mysql -B -N $@ -e "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'SHOW GRANTS FOR \'', user, '\'@\'', host, '\';'
    ) AS query FROM mysql.user" | \
  mysql $@ | \
  sed 's/\(GRANT .*\)/\1;/;s/^\(Grants for .*\)/## \1 ##/;/##/{x;p;x;}'
}
```

The first mysql command uses SQL to generate valid SQL which is piped to the second mysql command. The output is then piped through sed to add pretty comments.

The $@ in the command will allow you to call it as:
mygrants --host=prod-db1 --user=admin --password=secret

You can use your full unix tool kit on this like so:

```
mygrants --host=prod-db1 --user=admin --password=secret | grep rails_admin | mysql --host=staging-db1 --user=admin --password=secret
```

That is THE right way to move users. Your MySQL ACL is modified with pure SQL.

Comment: This is actually a nice bash helper function that works great. Take the output from that and be able to run on the new server and the privileges would be entered properly and accurately.

Comment: I love your function, today it saved me a lot of work. Thank you, thank you, thank you...

Comment: Love it. This has saved me at least an hour of work!

Comment: This is great but it has one big flaw. An extra "\" is added to underscores in database names, so if you have for example a user with specific privileges on a database called foo_bar, it will be rendered as foo\\_bar instead of foo\_bar, so that won't be imported correctly. At least, this happens if you save the output from you script into a SQL file and then import it into the new server. I haven't tried the direct piping of export and import in a single line.

Comment: Isn't `_` a special character, a wildcard character, so it has to be escaped? But I think it has to be `\_` and not `\\_`. And I am getting `\\_` when I run the command. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668591/grant-with-database-name-wildcard-in-mysql).

Comment: Be careful with this command. If you have in `user` table an user with host `%`, but then in `db` table you have entries where `host` is an explicit value, those entries in `db` table are not retrieved using this method.

Comment: @matteo Add `-r` to the 2nd mysql command in the function and the double escapes won't be output by `mysql`. eg: `mysql -r $@`

Comment: This answer not only gave me the mechanism i was looking for, but also gave me several leads for learning quite a bit.  Thank you much!

Answer (score 61):

There are two methods for extracting SQL Grants from a MySQL Instance

METHOD #1

You can use [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-show-grants.html) from Percona Toolkit

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
pt-show-grants ${MYSQL_CONN} > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

METHOD #2

You can emulate `pt-show-grants` with the following

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

Either method will produce a pure SQL dump of the MySQL grants. All there is left to do is to execute the script on a new server:

```
mysql -uroot -p -A < MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: pt-show-grants is exactly what you want for this, it works great.

Comment: Percona is just pure awesomeness.

Comment: But answer #2 is just as good and will work without additional software!

Comment: If you are moving to 8.0, the GRANTs and PASSWORD stuff need changing.

Answer (score 15):

Richard Bronosky's answer was extremely useful for me. Many thanks!!!

Here is a small variation which was useful for me. It is helpful for transfering users e.g. between two Ubuntu installations running phpmyadmin. Just dump privileges for all users apart from root, phpmyadmin and debian-sys-maint. The code is then

```
mygrants()
{
mysql -B -N $@ -e "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(
'SHOW GRANTS FOR ''', user, '''@''', host, ''';'
) AS query FROM mysql.user WHERE user NOT IN ('root','phpmyadmin','debian-sys-maint')"  | \
mysql $@ | \
sed 's/\(GRANT .*\)/\1;/;s/^\(Grants for .*\)/## \1 ##/;/##/{x;p;x;}'
}
```

Comment: If you look at my example where I `grep rails_admin` you can infer how to do this without making a special function for every edge case. Use grep's "invert-match" option like so: `mygrants --host=prod-db1 --user=admin --password=secret | grep -Ev 'root|phpmyadmin|debian-sys-maint'  | mysql --host=staging-db1 --user=admin --password=secret `

Answer (score 7):

Or, utilize percona-toolkit (former maatkit) and use `pt-show-grants` (or `mk-show-grants`) for that purpose. No need for cumbersome scripts and/or stored procedures.

Answer (score 6):

You can mysqldump the 'mysql' database and import to the new one; a flush_privileges or restart will be required and you'll definitely want to back up the existing mysq db first.

To avoid removing your existing privileges, make sure to append rather than replace rows in the privilege tables (db, columns_priv, host, func, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @nedm. Seems like the annoying cPanel server I'm trying to get the dbs off doesn't show the db 'mysql'. Otherwise I'd test and affirm your answer. Once I figure that out I'll check back. Thanks.

Comment: That is unfortunate but understandable, you are probably prevented from accessing any database but the ones directly owned by your user on a shared db.

Comment: Ouch, yeah, without access to 'mysql' it will be difficult to do anything related to users or permissions. Do you have command line access? Can you run mysqldump from the terminal or command line (NOT from the mysql shell)? 

mysqldump -u username -ppassword mysql > mysqldump.sql

Comment: The db 'mysql' was accessible from the Cpanel WHM if I logged in as 'root'. From there I can access a version of phpmyadmin which has the 'mysql' database containing permissions

Comment: Merging into a existing mysql schema, data extracted from a mysql schema via mysqldump is almost certain to be problematic. You are manipulating a complex schema with enforced relationships, etc. This schema is so complex, in fact, that they created dedicated SQL syntax (GRANT, REVOKE, DROP USER, etc.) for dealing with it. Your extract, however, consists of only INSERT statements. I'm running out of characters here. Need I continue?

Comment: No, you don't need to continue--it's clear you don't like messing with the mysql db.  However, it's not so mysterious as you make it sound, and it's even described as a recommended way to restore user and privilege data in the mysql documentation at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/6.0/en/backup-database-restore-quick-guide.html

Comment: I think your mygrants script is actually a pretty elegant way of copying permissions on a Linux box.  However, for small-medium number of users, I've had good luck copying and importing the mysql database, editing the dump file as necessary -- if users are duplicated on the new box, simply edit the dump file and comment out those INSERTs in the user table.  Privileges for the restored dbs from the old box will then be copied.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do it as a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spShowGrants()
    READS SQL DATA
    COMMENT 'Show GRANT statements for users'
BEGIN
    DECLARE v VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET utf8;
    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(
        'SHOW GRANTS FOR ', user, '@', host, ';'
    ) AS query FROM mysql.user;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN END;  
    OPEN c;
    WHILE TRUE DO
        FETCH c INTO v;
        SET @v = v;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @v;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE c;
END
```

and call it with

```
$ mysql -p -e "CALL spShowGrants" mysql
```

then pipe the output through Richards sed command to get a backup of the privileges.

Answer (score 5):

How about a PHP script? :)

View source on this script and you will have all the privileges listed:

```
//connect
mysql_select_db("mysql", mysql_connect("localhost","root",""));

//create grants select statements
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''', user, '''@''', host, ''';') AS query FROM user");

//iterate through grants
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    //run grant query
    $rs2 = mysql_query($row['query']);
    //iterate through results
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)){
        //print results
        echo $row2[0] . ";\n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While it appears @Richard Bronosky's answer is the correct one, I came across this question after trying to migrate a set of databases from one server to another and the solution was much simpler:

```
server1$ mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > dbdump.sql

server2$ mysql -u root -p < dbdump.sql
```

At this point, all my data was visible if I logged in as `root`, the `mysql.user` table had everything in it I was expecting, but I couldn't log in as any of the other users and found this question assuming I'd have to re-issue the `GRANT` statements.

However, it turns out that the mysql server simply needed to be restarted for the updated privileges in the `mysql.*` tables to take effect:

```
server2$ sudo restart mysql
```

Hopefully that helps someone else achieve what should be a simple task!

Comment: Oh, and my situation was slightly different to the OP's, in that I wasn't trying to merge a dump into a server with existing databases/users.

Comment: You don't actually have to restart MySQLd to 'update the privileges'. It can be done with the MySQL command 'flush privileges;'

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it works only when both source and destination MySQL version are the same. Otherwise you might have issues because source mysql.user table has different columns than destination mysql.user table, for example.

Answer (score 2):

**create a shell script file with the following code:**

##############################################3

```
echo "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (\"show grants for '\", user, \"'@'\", host, \"';\") AS query FROM mysql.user; " >   script.sql    
echo "*** You will be asked to enter the root password twice ******"    
mysql -u root -p  < script.sql > output.sql ;    
cat output.sql | grep show > output1.sql  ; rm output.sql -f ; 
mysql -u root -p  < output1.sql > output.sql ;
clear
echo "-----Exported Grants-----"    
cat  output.sql ; rm  output.sql   output1.sql -f    
echo "-------------------------"
rm  script.sql -f
```

#

****then run it on the shell like this:
you will be asked to enter the root password twice and then the GRANTS SQL will be displayed on the screen.****

Answer (score 0):

One-liner doing pretty much the same as the awesome `pt-show-grants`:

```
mysql --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g'
```

Based on unix tools only, no additional software needed.

Execute from within a bash shell, assumed is you have a working `.my.cnf` where the password of your `mysql root` user can be read.

Comment: i duplicated half of @rolandomysqldba 's post after coming back half a year later, i just realized.

Answer (score 0):

A challenge often encountered with some of the shell-based and command-line-based answers here is trying to execute them on a remote server -- the level of escaping of all the ticks and double-quotes and backslashes gets insane. Here is a way this can be done, from the command-line on a remote server:

```
cat  << EOQ | ssh $REMOTE_SERVER 'mysql -B -N  mysql | mysql -B -N ' | mysql 
 SELECT CONCAT('show grants for \'', user,'\'@\'', host, '\'\;') FROM user WHERE user != 'root' AND user != ''
EOQ
```

This command logs into the remote server remotely (here, we assume passwords are not needed with ssh keys and mysql/my.cnf/client configurations), executes the query which generates the `show grants` commands, a second mysql execution runs the generated commands, and the final mysql in the pipeline is executed on the local server which applies those `show grants` output on the local server.

The "root" user is not copied for security reasons.