# Changing collation of all tables and columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried to do this: https://serverfault.com/a/65572/603515

But I changed it slightly to target only the database I want to change.

```
mysql -B -N --host=localhost --user=root --password=secret \
      -e "select CONCAT('alter table ',TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',
          TABLE_NAME,' charset=utf8mb4_bin;')
        from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'usda_nndsr'; 
     select CONCAT('alter table ',TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME,' alter column ',
         COLUMN_NAME,' charset=utf8mb4_bin;')
         from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='usda_nndsr';" |
     mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=secret
```

but it's telling me:

```
mysql: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

ERROR 1115 (42000) at line 1: Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4_bin'
```

I want `utf8mb4_bin` because I heard MySQL utf8 is not real utf8 using only 3 bytes.

How can I edit my query or command to make the change. Currently it is the default swedish collation.

MySQL version:

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.32, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utf8mb4_bin` is a "Collation", not a "character set".  The corresponding charset is simply `utf8mb4`.

Versions before 5.5 did not have charset utf8mb4.

There is no simply to convert all text columns of all table in an entire database.

This will convert all text (`VARCHAR` and `TEXT`) columns of a single table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

I would not trust the complex mysql that you propose, even after fixing the charset.  There are several issues that I am unclear on when using `-e`.  Instead, I would run the `SELECT` to generate a list of `ALTERs`, then copy&paste those into `mysql`.

Changing the "table" only changes the default charset for any *future* columns you might add.

`CONVERT TO` changes the columns -- both altering the encoding in the data and changing the definition of the column.  Are the columns currently `utf8`?  What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: You mean just run this query and copy and paste the resulting SQL queries?`SELECT CONCAT('alter table ',TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME,'charset=utf8mb4_bin;') from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'usda_nndsr'; select CONCAT('alter table', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME,' alter column ',COLUMN_NAME,' charset=utf8mb4_bin;') from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'usda_nndsr';
`

Comment: Change the charset.  Add two more schemas to the exclusion list.  Are the two `SELECTs` different?

Comment: I'm sorry but as a novice I don't even know what you mean by add two more schemas so I'm going to do it manually.

Comment: @seizouki - Be sure not to change any tables in the databases named `mysql`.

Comment: There were some issues with not being able to change collation of columns used as foreign keys.

Comment: @seizouki - Drop the FKs; make the charset changes; then recreate the FKs.  While you are at it, make sure you end up with 'identical' specifications for any columns involved in a `JOIN`.

Comment: by specifications, do you mean things like character set and collation?

Comment: @seizouki - Yes.  Also numeric (`INT`, etc) versus text (`VARCHAR`, etc).  That is don't `JOIN` and `INT` in one table to a `VARCHAR` in another table.  (Sizes and `NULL` are not critical.)